# Does GitHub have an escape character for their markup?

Tags: github, formatting, html, special-characters

**Background**
I realize that markup is implementation without a specification but it basically is just a tiny little node stemming from SGML and the like. On GitHub I always use the ` symbol with a closed back tic to indicate code when it's inline with a sentence. This often happens with bash/shell scripting in this particular scenario.

**Example #1 - Block Code**
If you are looking for oracle's creg ini file you would know that on Oracle Cloud you can view it using `view /var/opt/oracle/creg/ORCL.ini`. However, this assumes you used the recommended settings for simple DBaaS provision. If you named your database MFG the command would be `view /var/opt/oracle/creg/MFG.ini`. Thankfully there is an environment variable that holds the database name. And if I were writing a simple bash script it would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/opt/oracle/creg/`printenv ORACLE_SID`.ini
```

So that prints fine in a block.

**Exampe #2 - Inline**
So if I simply want to tell a user to 'cd /var/opt/oracle/creg/`printenv ORACLE_SID`.ini' I shouldn't have to make a block.

**Question**
IS there an escape character in GitHub's markup implementation? I want the entire thing to show just like a normal line of code. It's better on StackOverflow on GitHub it basically breaks the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub uses Markdown (specifically a custom 'flavour' thereof), and in Markdown you can escape backticks in code by using double backticks: https://github.com/mattcone/markdown-guide/blob/master/_basic-syntax/code.md#escaping-backticks

> If the word or phrase you want to denote as code includes one or more backticks, you can escape it by enclosing the word or phrase in double backticks (``).

Comment: right after creating the post I attempted to escape using ('') however it gave me a 500 error.  Then when I navigated to the markdown gist it showed incorrectly (it showed all as code, but with two open and two close backticks ).   You can see my history here.  There is a thread on github about it now. Somehow it magically fixed itself with no revision change so someone at github definitely took notice

Comment: What if I'd like to escape triple backticks?

Answer (score 1):

For both a single backtick and triple backtick, it seems that github (and stackexchange) support a backslash escape:

```
cd /var/opt/oracle/creg/\`printenv ORACLE_SID\`.ini
```

gives:
cd /var/opt/oracle/creg/`printenv ORACLE_SID`.ini

and:

````
\```
stuff
\```
````

gives
```
stuff
```
on stackexchange, but github doesn't always wrap lines, so this stays as 3 lines.

Backslash also works for escaping underscore `_` and asterisk `*` (otherwise italics, or bold when doubled).

For other markup, Markdown supports using html for things the regular syntax doesn't support. This is true for the [GitHub flavored Markdown](https://github.github.com/gfm/) see [Raw HTML](https://github.github.com/gfm/#raw-html).

It isn't as simple as a backslash escape, but using the HTML `span` element does work to escape special github characters such as hash `#` and at sign `@`.

e.g.:

```
install the <span>@</span>latest markdown package, it's <span>#</span>1
```

gives: install the @latest markdown package, it's #1

without creating a link to a (possibly non existent) github user or issue.